# First Computer built by a single person

Tags: history

Who was it that built the first functional electronic computer as a single-person effort? It must have been back in the mini-computer era, 1970 or so, but who was it?

Comment: First programmable electronic computer - possibly Tommy Flowers in 1943.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tommy_Flowers  Not sure what you mean by functional.

Comment: Interesting Wiki link - thank you, but I don't think Flowers built the machine by himself. The article says he was working in a lab, so he must have had assistance.
By functional, I mean actually worked.

Comment: Zuse worked mostly alone I think.

Comment: Analog or digital? Electronic or mechanical? Does "building" include smelting ore and doing your own photolithography to fabricate integrated circuits, or is it enough to plug a CPU into a socket?

Comment: How about designed from scratch, wired up from scratch with integrated circuits?

Comment: In building the Z1, Zuse "enlisted the help of his sister, his circle of friends, and his theater group [...]. His father, Emil Zuse, also sawed sheet metal parts with a fretsaw." (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z1_(Rechner), my translation) The design was entirely his own, though -- and it was electro-mechanical, not electronic.

Comment: This is one of those questions where the answer depends more on the exact wording of the question than anything else. Digital or analog computer? Programmable or not? Stored-program or plugboard? What does single-person effort mean? What parts would they be allowed? And so on and so forth.

Comment: [Wikipedia article on Colossus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colossus_computer#Design_and_construction) says, "Flowers and his team of some _fifty people_...spent eleven months from early February 1943 designing and building...[the] Mark 1 Colossus..."

Comment: Re, "...first functional electronic computer..." I saw a list once. Somebody googled for "world's first computer," and they made a list of around thirty different machines that had been called "world's first computer" by thirty-some different authors. Some of those probably were on the list through ignorance: An author simply was unaware of some earlier machine. But, I reckon at least a few of them made the list as [_true scotsmen_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_true_Scotsman). As in, "We can't count _that_ one. It wasn't a _real_ computer. It's not a real computer unless..."

Comment: The [kenbak](https://www.bbc.com/news/business-34639183)  by John Blankenbaker perhaps?

Comment: @SetiNet I built one of my own (no help from anyone) in 1974 (age 18, at the time) using 7400 series parts. There's a newspaper article on it, in fact, in the Hillsboro Argus. But I'm very sure I wasn't the first such. But that sets a number for you that is to be beat.

Comment: 8-bit TTL homebrew machines were in the air at the time.  The UK Amateur Computer Club's [Weeny Bitter](https://newall.ca/acc/Vol3-Issue3.pdf) design from 1975 was one such.

Comment: The Kenbak seems to be the first computer built by a single person (1971)
I started mine in 1971 but didn't have it working until 1976.
https://www.seti.net/NewToSETINet/aboutSETINet/about.php

Comment: The [Practical Electronics Analogue Computer](https://worldradiohistory.com/UK/Practical-Electronics/60s/Practical-Electronics-1968-01.pdf) was published in 1968, though presumably built by its designer before then.  (I think this was the first copy of *PE* I ever bought; at that point I barely knew which end of a soldering iron to hold, so the PEAC was way out of my league)

Comment: @another-dave Your link sure gets to the point of what "electronic computer" means to the OP. Does analog count? If it does then already we've got analog and digital electronics. A question might follow: "What about analog and digital mechanicals? I studied a book from the early 1950's that was a magnificent trove on various mechanical arrangements to perform log and anti-log, as well as sum and difference. Some with small control stores, set manually, that allowed the machinery to perform sets of steps. It's often more important to ask an incisive question than the answers one gets.

Comment: Is there anyone here that would confuse a mechanical difference machine with a computer? I would not, and I don't need to create a definition to do it.

Comment: Well, you need to set the definitions and limits of your question, as @MichaelGraf suggested. What is a _computer_ to you? In the analog world, a simple operational amplifier can be a computer, because with an input it does some transformation and outputs the result.

Comment: What is a single-person effort? Most computers built after the very first few ones used theories and parts that other had used earlier. Is it a single-person effort if someone teaches me how TTL logic can be used for other things first? If I read a data book on TTL logic (who didn't back in the days?) can't it be argued that the author(s) of that data book helped me?

Comment: @snips-n-snails I'm pretty sure those guys plugging CPUs into Sockets are *most probably* not the first ones :) still you're right, the question should clearify that

Comment: @SetiNet - nevertheless, there were mechanical devices which were and are considered 'computers', the [differential analyser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_analyser) for one.

Comment: What's the difference between a TTL chip manufactured by some third party, bought for the Kenback, and a metal plate cut by Zuse's friends for the Z1? Either both are build by a single man or neither.

Comment: Anyone would think they had stumbled into a philosophy conversation if they had read the comments here.  Nope, I don't need to define a damn thing.